# Make navigation div expand entire height of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation div on the left of my page. I want it to span the entire height of the page.Following is the html and css for the structure.

```css
#wrapper{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -112px;
}
.main_wrap{
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.container{
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.main-sidebar{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 195px;
  z-index: 810;
}
.sidebar{
  height: 100%;
}
.content_wrap{
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.content_box{
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
HTML:
<div id=“wrapper>
  <div class=“main_wrap”>
    <div class=“container>
      <div class="main-sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar">
         <!—left navigation part goes here—>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=“content_wrap”>
   <div class=“content_box”>
    <!—content part goes here—>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Why are you defining `height` twice in `#wrapper` ?

Comment: I think the problem is `height: auto !important;`. You say, height automatic. So it makes the height to what the content inside is. And you say `!important`, so it will do this defiantly.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `height` twice in `#wrapper`. Remove `height: auto !important;` if you want it to take 100% of the height, because `auto` makes the div fit to its content. The `!important` makes `auto` override `100%` you defined after.

Your `wrapper` class should then look like this :

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -112px;
}
```

Comment: Well I have removed the double definition of height, but I need to keep the structure in this way only.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. I didn't modify any structure, I just told you to remove one line of CSS, you shouldn't have to touch the HTML.

Comment: Then I don't know what's wrong. Are you sure you posted everything relevant ? Here is a jsfiddle with this exact code, except I colored the left nav in red. You can see it takes all the height : http://jsfiddle.net/8zxwmxe5/1/

Comment: Some double quotes were missing in my code, when I fixed the quotes, left nav overlapped the "Box right". This is the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/8zxwmxe5/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh`:

```
 #wrapper{
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto -112px;
}
```

But it's not supported in all browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

I would do it with javascript:

```
   function resize()
   {
         var heights = window.innerHeight;
         document.getElementsById("wrapper").style.height = heights + "px";
   }
   resize();
   window.onresize = function() {
         resize();
   };
```

Now it is your choice...

Answer (score 0):

A couple of changes are needed.
Remove "position: absolute" and add "float: left" to .main-sidebar

```
.main-sidebar{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 195px;
  z-index: 810;
  float: left;
}
```

Put the content_wrap div right after main-sidebar div

```
...
          <div class="main-sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar">
             <!—left navigation part goes here—>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class=“content_wrap”>
            <div class=“content_box”>
              <!—content part goes here—>
           </div>
          </div>
...
```

remove the double definition of height in #wrapper

```
#wrapper{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -112px;
}
```